# Why am I getting "IndexError: list index out of range", during for loop, midway through beautiful soup parse?

Tags: python, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse image sources from 82 URL's I have stored in a list called `site_links` with beautifulsoup. I have no idea why this loop is throwing an error midway through. Any thoughts?

Error:

```
/images/africa/egypt/abu-gorab-sun-temples/sun-temple-of-niuserre-main.jpg
/images/africa/egypt/abu-roash-pyramid-of-djedefre/abu-roash-pyramid-of-djedefre-main.jpg
/images/africa/egypt/abusir-necropolis/abusir-necropolis-main1.jpg
/images/africa/egypt/dashur-bent-pyramid/dashur-bent-pyramid-main1.jpg
/images/africa/egypt/giza-plateau-pyramid-complex/giza-plateau-pyramid-complex-main1.jpg
/images/africa/egypt/giza-plateau-sphinx/giza-plateau-sphinx-main1.jpg
/images/africa/egypt/zawyet-el-aryan-unfinished-pyramid/zawyet-el-aryan-unfinished-pyramid-main2.jpg
/images/africa/egypt/abu-simbel-temple-complex/abu-simbel-temple-complex-main1.jpg
/images/africa/egypt/aswan-elephantine-island/aswan-elephantine-island-main.jpg
/images/africa/egypt/denderra-temple-complex/denderra-temple-complex-main2.jpg
/images/africa/egypt/thebes-karnak-temple-complex/thebes-karnak-temple-complex-main5.jpg
/images/africa/egypt/thebes-luxor-temple/thebes-luxor-temple-main3.jpg
/images/africa/ethiopia/axum-obelisks/axum-obelisks-main1.jpg
/images/africa/ethiopia/lalibela-rock-hewn-churches/lalibela-rock-hewn-churches-main3.jpg
/images/asia/india/ellora-kailasa-temple/ellora-kailasa-temple-main1.jpg
/images/asia/india/warangal-warangal-fort/warangal-warangal-fort-main1.jpg
/images/asia/indonesia/west-java-gunung-padang/west-java-gunung-padang-main1.jpg
/images/asia/japan/yonaguni-yonaguni-monument/yonaguni-yonaguni-monument-main1.jpg
/images/asia/laos/xiangkhouang-plain-of-jars/xiangkhouang-plain-of-jars-main1.jpg
/images/asia/lebanon/baalbek-baalbek-temple-complex/baalbek-baalbek-temple-complex-main4.jpg
/images/asia/micronesia/pohnpei-nan-madol/pohnpei-nan-madol-main1.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/J/Google Drive/pythonProjects/Megalith Map/data_scrape.py", line 41, in <module>
    img = soup.find('div', {'itemprop' : 'blogPost'}).find_all('img')[0].get('src')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My Code:

```
site_links = []
site_img = []
# PARSES ALL IMAGE SOURCES ON THE WEBSITE
for i in site_links:
        r = requests.get(i).text
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r, 'html5lib')
        img = soup.find('div', {'itemprop' : 'blogPost'}).find_all('img')[0].get('src')
        if '.jpg' in img:
                site_img.append(site_img)
                print(img)
```

Comment: It looks like at some point `find_all('img')` returns an empty list. Check the data being scraped. There could be an oddity in the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of `find_all` is a `list`-like. If you attempt to index it when it is empty, it will raise an error.

That suggests that it cannot find anything matching your specified criteria on the page. To handle such cases, you should check first if `find_all` has found anything, and only then index it:

```
site_links = []
site_img = []
# PARSES ALL IMAGE SOURCES ON THE WEBSITE
for i in site_links:
    r = requests.get(i).text
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r, 'html5lib')
    images = soup.find('div', {'itemprop' : 'blogPost'}).find_all('img')
    if images:
        img = images[0].get('src', '')
        if '.jpg' in img:
            site_img.append(site_img)
            print(img)

    else:
        print('No image found.')
```

Note that I have also modified the `get` call to return the empty string if `src` cannot be found, which will also prevent raising an error since it would return `None` otherwise, which will cause the following test for inclusion to fail.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. The problem was no image existed in the webpage bs4 was parsing. Is there a reason why you chose to add 'if images:' and placing [0].get('src', '') in there instead of just leaving it at the end of my original line of code? Also, how did you know adding a comma after 'src' would return an empty string?

Comment: `if images` will evaluate to `False` if `images` is empty, which represents the absence of images on the page currently being parsed. Only if it is *not* empty can we call `get` on the first element. As for your second question, I tested it! I had a hunch it would mirror the semantics of the Python `dict`, where `get` takes an optional second argument that will be returned if the key searched for cannot be found.

Comment: I actually found this is skipping over some, but not all, elements in 'site_links' that do not have an image. Any ideas why this is happening? I noticed this when I was trying to append 'No image found' to  'site_img' and when I tried to add it to a data frame I received this error. 'ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index' and when I went to look at the length of the list it returned 70 not 82. Thanks for any help on this issue.

Comment: @prime90 That would suggest that your `find_all` statement is raising a false positive. Try storing the HTML of such pages and analysing them.